# Increase the contrast of 'similar questions' pane on unix stackexchange

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

I am writing a question right now on unix stackexchange and on the right there is a pane with a blue background and orange text. It is hard to read.

[image]

My suggestion is you change the colors of that pane so that it's easier to read. For example, this site's similar questions pane looks fine, the contrast is good.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's fine now (since the [latest design update](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3429/site-design-updates)).

[image: similar questions screenshot]